# How can I hide the first Y Axis tick mark on ChartJs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chart.js

My first tick mark is messing with the padding of the bottom of my chart. Is there any way to tell ChartJS to hide the first Y axis tick mark/label?

From my other research there is a function called afterBuildTicks that you can define to do something with the tick marks but I am unsure of the approach.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to always remove the first tick mark?

JS

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

    // Create gradient
    grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(170.000, 600.000, 150.000, 0.000);

    // Add colors
    grd.addColorStop(0.000, 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1.000)');
    grd.addColorStop(0.200, 'rgba(191, 255, 0, 1.000)');
    grd.addColorStop(0.400, 'rgba(221, 255, 0, 1.000)');
    grd.addColorStop(0.600, 'rgba(255, 229, 0, 1.000)');
    grd.addColorStop(0.800, 'rgba(255, 144, 0, 1.000)');
    grd.addColorStop(1.000, 'rgba(255, 50, 0, 1.000)');




    var data = {
        labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"],
        datasets: [
            {
                lineTension: 0.1,
                backgroundColor: grd,
                borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                borderDash: [],
                borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                pointBorderWidth: 1,
                pointHoverRadius: 5,
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                pointRadius: 1,
                pointHitRadius: 10,
                data: [0, 100, 250, 400, 400, 400, 500, 700, 900, 1000, 1000, 1300, 1300, 1100, 900, 700, 500, 300, 100, 0],
                spanGaps: false,
            }
        ]
    };


    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: data,
        options: {
            legend: {
              display: false
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true,
                        callback: function(value, index, values) {
                                return value + '°';
                        },
                        mirror: true,
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false,
                        drawBorder: false,

                    },
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    display: false,
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }]
            },

        },
    });
```

HTML

```
<div style="height: 600px; width:600px; border: 2px solid blue; margin-left: 10px">
        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

I'd need to see the markup for the axis and ticks to be more specific, but you want to do something like this:

```
.ticks:first-of-type {
    display: none;
}
```

Where `.ticks` is the class name of the tick elements.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The entire chart is rendered as the canvas element. There is not a node for each tick.

Comment: @Our_Benefactors As I said, I would need to see the markup to be sure.  OP, can you post (a portion of) the resulting html

Comment: here is a snippet from my project using chart.js 

<canvas height="383" id="myChart" chartname="Trends in Death Rates" charttype="line" width="767" style="display: block; width: 767px; height: 383px;"></canvas>

As you can see, there is not really any markup to work with.